# Upload large database file in EasyPHP

Tags: php, mysql, upload, phpmyadmin, easyphp

I have just downloaded the latest EasyPHP DevServer 16.1.1 to develop website while trying to upload a database file of 50 MB I got an an upload limit exceeding error. If any one of you know how to change the default upload or import size limit in PhpMyAdmin.

I am using EasyPHP latest DEVSERVER 16.1.1

Currently my server is limited to 2MB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

go on the easyphp panel, configuration --> php, find file php.ini and change upload_max_filesize, set it 64M.

Comment: I have checked the EasyPHP panel from the task bar but could not find any configuration. If you could give me direct folder link so that I can browse and edit the php.ini file.

Comment: there are two, try to change the value in both:
first is in C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-Devserver-16.1\eds-binaries\php\php704vc14x86x161022005756
second is in C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-Devserver-16.1\eds-binaries\php\php5619vc11x86x161022005756

Comment: you should also change in both the value of max_execution_time to 300

Comment: Thanks pacc88 I have edited post_max_size in php.ini file of the both directories you mentioned above and it worked.

Comment: perfect, good job, and do not forget to increase the max_execution_time value to 300 or may have a problem